# Why the renewcommand doesn't work as I expect?

Tags: environments

I re-defined two environment

```
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}
\newenvironment{examp}{\begin{exmp}}{\renewcommand{\proofname}{Sol.}\end{exmp}}
\newenvironment{pf}{\begin{proof}}{\renewcommand{\proofname}{Proof}\end{proof}}
```

to make sure that when the proofname which is **right after the `examp` environment** should change to **Solution**, while keep it be **Proof** for other environment(THEOREM, Lemma and so on).

But it seems that it is not worked as I expected. WHY?

Comment: Please always post a complete document that demonstrates the problem and all packages used (there are several implementations of `\newtheorem` for example in different packages.)

Comment: I just want to ask the logic part, not the grammar part, so it seems useless to post the whole stuff here.

Comment: _every_ question should have a complete example document if you expect people to actually test their answers. Without knowing how proof is defined (which depends on information you have not supplied) I don't see how it's possible to even guess an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I assume `proof` is the environment provided by `amsthm`.)

This can't work, because every environment forms a group and so `\renewcommand{\proofname}{Sol.}` is forgotten as soon as `\end{exmp}` is performed.

You *may* want to use global redefinitions:

```
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}
\newenvironment{examp}
  {\begin{exmp}}
  {\gdef\proofname{Sol.}\end{exmp}}
\newenvironment{pf}[1][\proofname]
  {\begin{proof}[#1]}
  {\gdef\proofname{Proof}\end{proof}}
```

but, of course, you're not safe as a `pf` environment is mandatory after `examp` or the next proof after a theorem would be called “Sol.”.

I'd simply prefer using

```
\begin{exmp}
Something
\end{exmp}
\begin{proof}[Sol.]
The solution
\end{proof}
```

or also define a `sol` environment

```
\newenvironment{sol}
  {\begin{proof}[Sol.]}
  {\end{proof}}
```

Since this is a different logical unit than a proof, it deserves its own name.

Comment: Thanks, I know the point now: because every environment forms a group and so \renewcommand{\proofname}{Sol.} is forgotten as soon as \end{exmp} is performed.